# I created my own CLI with Node.js that uses .env, but I can't find it when it was installed globally

Tags: javascript, node.js, command-line-interface

I created a simple CLI with Node.js (and some accompanying packages, like inquirer, boxen, etc.), and it uses `dotenv` to manage the `.env` file.

If I run the CLI from it's root directory, it works without any problem (`node .`). However, when I install it globally (npm i -g .), I can only run it in the terminal as the name I set in the `package.json` file; it can't find the .env.

From what I can tell, all the global install does is [symbolic link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbolic_link) the project and also add the alias to the Node.js path, so I can run it from wherever I want in the the terminal, but I'm struggling to find a way to get the `.env` read, so the CLI will the function properly.

I've tried other `.env` packages (I don't know a lot about it, so knowing the proper way to reference it could be my main issue).

I've tried changing the `dotenv.config()` to include some form of path reference, but my build is set up as a `module` build, so it complains that I'm using *imports* instead of *require* (`import * as dotenv from 'dotenv'`) which, like I said; works fine from the root directory if I run `node .`.

I figured since it was just symbolic linking the folder and creating the alias, it'd be able to read the `.env` file without issue. But I really have no clue what else to try.

**Index.js**

```js
#! /usr/bin/env node
import fs from 'fs'
import * as dotenv from 'dotenv'
dotenv.config()

let token = process.env.PERSONAL_TOKEN

async function loadUserOptions() {
  const client = new Client({ apiKey: token })
}
```

At this point, if I ran it via the CLI name, it would fail as `PERSONAL_TOKEN` can't be found, but if I run it from it's root directory with `node .`, it works just fine.

---

So, the solution I ended up going with after realizing (thanks to you lovely folks) that a `.env` for a CLI was a stupid idea, was something more purpose-built. I found a pretty solid package called [Conf](https://www.npmjs.com/package/conf) which persists command-line data in a pretty simple fashion, which allows me to just grab input prompts from the user and store the necessary data.

Comment: Have you tried using `__dirname` or `__filename`?

Comment: @NickMcCurdy Unfortunately, I get `ReferenceError: __dirname is not defined in ES module scope
This file is being treated as an ES module because it has a '.js' file extension` because I'm using `imports` instead of `require` when trying to use either of those.

@Isaac It has a bunch of sensitive information in it pertaining to the company I work for, but I'll rip that out as best I can and post relevant code.

Comment: Seems very weird to include a .env file with a cli package, adjacent to the installed package location. Why not just ad some environment variables in your bashrc?

Comment: @Evert As this is my first time with this kind of project, my only experience (as a full-time Laravel developer) has been with `.env` files. I had it in the back of my head that it probably isn't the best solution, it's just the solution *I* know. The only problem I can see with your way is it's not as user-friendly to add the token you get from the 3rd-party service provider. The the other issue is I'd have to figure out which shell the user is using. I'm not very knowledgable in this department which admittedly, is a personal issue I'll have to overcome. Thanks for the idea! Gonna try it.

Comment: So generally with CLIs that are installed globally, you don't ask users of your package to hunt down a .env file in your installation path of your package and change it there. Instead, you either provide a predictable place where configuration is made (usually `~/.config`) or you just let them set it in their shell environment.

Comment: `dotenv` is really just a 'hack' to avoid having to set environment variables the normal way, which is useful for working on source code/websites but not needed as much for your use-case.

Comment: @Evert Understood. You're right, now that I think about it. That was a poor decision on my part and I've already started on the path of correcting it. Thank you for the guidance. Not new to development, but definitely new to the Nix* world, so command-line stuff is... a tad outside my wheel house.

Comment: Could you use a netrc or credential manager instead?

Comment: @NickMcCurdy I'm honestly not 100% sure. Again, this is mostly pretty new to me, so it's all exploration and learning at this point. I went with `.env` because I'm familiar with it, or rather *more* familiar with it than anything else. However, I think I found a pretty good solution to my issue. Thanks for the ideas!

Comment: In that case you should post it as an answer.

Answer (score -1):

The proper solution (at least, the one that worked for me) was to use [Conf](https://www.npmjs.com/package/conf). The beauty of `Conf` is that it stores any data you ask it to in a similar fashion to LocalStorage. The syntax is super easy to remember, and it works really well for my particular use case.